# Sinatra vs Node.js performance for a simple REST API

Tags: node.js, sinatra

This is not a holy war question, I'm just asking **what framework would be the best choice in terms of performance in my specific project**.

I'm writing a REST API and choosing between Node.js and Sinatra. One method of the API will be used very frequently (± 100k requests per day).
This request is very simple: select one row from a database, make a few calculations, update one row in a database.

But, as I said, it will be called frequently and I need to choose a framework that will perform better in this case.
This is a simple app and in this case I don't care which framework is easier or "better", just interested in the performance. I already wrote a prototype in Sinatra, the whole app is less than 150 lines of code.

I read about Node.js, but never created a real app with it.
**Will Node.js be a significantly better choice for this project in terms of performance and scalability?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100k requests a day is roughly a request per second assuming a flat distribution of requests during the day. Both solutions will probably serve that without a problem. **You're probably falling into the premature optimisation trap**.

That being said, Javascript, because of it's asynchronous nature is significantly better at high i/o than Ruby (Sinatra is just a simple web framework, Node is just how you run Javascript on a server).

Now as per the "what should I do", I suspect most people would tell you to use the prototype you already have working and use it until it's no longer good, if it ever comes to it. Seeing it's such a small app it shouldn't be a problem to rewrite it later with Node anyway!